# Métodos em java?

Tags: java

Estou desenvolvendo esse algoritmo simples de agenda mas os métodos `listar()` e `buscar()` não estão funcionando, eu escolho e é simplesmente ignorado.

```
package strings;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Agenda {
    static String contato[];
    private static String[] vetor;
    private static int MAX = 10;
    private static String []nome = new String[MAX];
    private static String []numero = new String[MAX];
    static Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    static int i;
    static int cont;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //APP - LISTA DE NOMES
        //Criar um método para cada opção
        //Integrar esse App ao banco de dados
        //Integrar front-end

        int operacao, i, contador=0;

        while(true) {
        System.out.println(" opção 1: Adicionar contato  ");
        System.out.println(" opção 2: Listar contatos    ");
        System.out.println(" opção 3: Buscar contato     ");
        System.out.println(" opção 4: Atualizar contato  ");
        System.out.println(" opção 5: Deletar contato    ");
        System.out.println(" DIGITE ZERO PARA SAIR       ");
        operacao = entrada.nextInt();
        switch (operacao) {
        case 1:
                //Adicionar contato
                adicionar(contato);
            break;
        case 2:
                //listar contatos
                listar();
            break;
        case 3:
                //Buscar contato
                buscar();
            break;

        case 4:
                //Atualizar contato
            break;
        case 5:
                String remove;
                System.out.println("Escolha um contato a ser removido ");
                remove = entrada.next();
                remover(remove);
            break;
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Sistema Finalizado!");
            break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Informe outro número");
        }
        }//fim do laço
    } //fim do Método main.

public static void adicionar(String[] contato) {
    int cont=0;
    System.out.println("Adicionar nome: ");
    nome[i] = entrada.next();
    System.out.println("Adicionar numero: ");
    numero[i] = entrada.next();
    cont++;
}

public static void listar() {
    for(int i = 0; i < cont; i++) {
        System.out.println("Nome: "+nome[i]);
        //System.out.println("Telefone: "+numero[i]);

    }
}
public static void buscar() {
    String buscar;
    System.out.println("Informe o nome a ser buscado: ");
    buscar = entrada.nextLine();
    for(i=0; i < cont; i++) {
        if(nome[i].equalsIgnoreCase(buscar)) {
            System.out.println("Nome "+nome[i]);
            System.out.println("Numero "+numero[i]);
        }
    }
}

public static void remover(String remove){

        for(int i=0; i < nome.length; i++) {
            if(nome[i].equalsIgnoreCase(remove)) {
                nome[i] = null;
                numero[i] = null;
                break;
            }
            break;
        } 

} 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema dos métodos `listar()` e `buscar()` é que `cont` sempre será zero. Quando você declara a variável estática:

```
static int cont;
```

Por padrão, ela é inicializada com o valor zero. Em seguida, se você alterar o método `listar()` para imprimir o valor de `cont`:

```
public static void listar() {
    System.out.println("Listando " + cont + " nomes");
    ....
```

Verá que o valor dela sempre é zero. E o problema está no método `adicionar()`, pois você está criando uma outra variável `cont`:

```
public static void adicionar(String[] contato) {
    int cont = 0;
```

Esta variável `cont` foi criada dentro do método, e por isso ela só existe durante a execução do mesmo (e ao final, é descartada). Por isso não adianta fazer `cont++` no final do método, pois isso está incrementando a variável local, não o `cont` estático.

Então podemos começar removendo esta variável de dentro do método, pois ela não faz sentido: se queremos um contador de todos os cadastros feitos, este contador não pode ser uma variável local ao método (que é criada e destruída a cada execução).

Podemos também mudar o nome dela para algo mais significativo (`cont` é genérico demais). Exemplo:

```
static int quantidadeCadastros = 0;
```

Assim eu sei exatamente o que esta variável significa. Isso facilita o entendimento do código em todos os lugares onde ela for usada, além de facilitar também caso você precise de outros contadores (em vez de criar `cont2`, `cont3`...)

Repare que também inicializei a variável com zero. Claro que neste caso não seria necessário, já que variáveis estáticas por padrão são inicializadas com zero, mas eu prefiro deixar explícito que o programa começa com nenhum cadastro feito.

Outro detalhe é que você está usando `i` no cadastro:

```
nome[i] = entrada.next();
```

Só que este `i` não está sendo incrementado (ou seja, todos os cadastros estão sendo guardados na mesma posição, já que o valor de `i` nunca muda).

Creio que neste caso seja melhor usar a própria variável `quantidadeCadastros` para isso, pois ela sempre sabe a quantidade de cadastros já feitos, e por isso já sabemos em qual posição do array deve ficar o próximo cadastro.

---

Existem ainda outros detalhes, como o fato de `next()` não aceitar nomes com espaços, por exemplo. Neste caso, seria melhor trocar por `nextLine()`.

Falando nisso, o `nextLine()` no método `buscar()` não está funcionando porque:

- ao fazer `operacao = entrada.nextInt()`, o *newline* (que seria o <kbd>ENTER</kbd> que digitamos) ao final da linha não é consumido pelo `Scanner`
- ao entrar no método `buscar()`, o `nextLine()` lê o *newline* da linha atual (a que teve o número digitado). Por isso o nome a ser buscado não é lido.

A solução, conforme sugerido [nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066), é simplesmente chamar `nextLine()` logo após ler o número:

```
operacao = entrada.nextInt();
entrada.nextLine();
```

Isso não interfere nas próximas chamadas de `nextLine()` (como a que é feita no método `buscar()`).

Outro detalhe é que no método `buscar()` você está usando o `i` estático dentro do `for`. Mas isso é desnecessário, pois este `i` só serve para percorrer o array e não há necessidade nenhuma de ter uma variável estática para isso. Então podemos remover o `static int i;`

Então o código ficaria assim:

```
// contador de cadastros
static int quantidadeCadastros = 0;

....
// no loop while, colocar nextLine() depois de ler o número da operação:
operacao = entrada.nextInt();
entrada.nextLine();
....


// usar o contador como índice do array
// e usar nextLine() para ler o nome completo (no caso de ter espaços no nome)
public static void adicionar(String[] contato) {
    System.out.println("Adicionar nome: ");
    nome[quantidadeCadastros] = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Adicionar numero: ");
    numero[quantidadeCadastros] = entrada.nextLine();
    quantidadeCadastros++;
}

public static void listar() {
    for (int i = 0; i < quantidadeCadastros; i++) {
        System.out.println("Nome: " + nome[i]);
        // System.out.println("Telefone: "+numero[i]);
    }
}

public static void buscar() {
    String buscar;
    System.out.println("Informe o nome a ser buscado: ");
    buscar = entrada.nextLine();
    System.out.println("buscar[" + buscar + "]");
    // usar "int i", em vez do "i" estático
    for (int i = 0; i < quantidadeCadastros; i++) {
        if (nome[i].equalsIgnoreCase(buscar)) {
            System.out.println("Nome " + nome[i]);
            System.out.println("Numero " + numero[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Outro detalhe está na opção para sair do programa:

```
case 0:
    System.out.println("Sistema Finalizado!");
    break;
```

Este `break` pertence ao `switch(operacao)`, não ao *loop* `while(true)`. Por isso a opção zero não vai sair do *loop*, e consequentemente, não vai sair do programa.

A [solução também já é conhecida](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22823427): basta dar um nome para o *loop*, e usar este mesmo nome no `break`. No exemplo abaixo escolhi um nome bem óbvio:

```
loop: while (true) { // nome bem óbvio para o loop while
    .....
    switch (operacao) {
        ....
        case 0:
            System.out.println("Sistema Finalizado!");
            break loop; // sair do loop
    }
} // fim do laço
```

Coloquei o nome `loop`, mas você pode colocar qualquer outro - só lembrando de usar o mesmo nome, tanto no `while` quanto no `break`.

---

Existem ainda outros detalhes, como esta linha dentro do método `main()`:

```
int operacao, i, contador = 0;
```

As variáveis `i` e `contador` não são usadas, então pode removê-las.

Há ainda outras coisas para melhorar. Se você não sabe de antemão a quantidade de cadastros que podem ser feitos, o melhor é usar [`java.util.List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) em vez de arrays.

Além disso, se quer agrupar dados (como o nome e o número), seria interessante criar uma classe para isso:

```
public class Cadastro {
    private String nome;
    private String numero;
    ... (construtores, getters/setters, etc)
}
```

E em vez de ter arrays de `Strings`, bastaria ter uma lista de cadastros:

```
// lista de cadastros, em vez de ter dois arrays de String
List<Cadastro> cadastros = new ArrayList<>();
```

No método `adicionar()`, bastaria usar `add()` para adicionar um cadastro:

```
... // ler nome e número

// adicionar o cadastro
Cadastro c = new Cadastro(nome, numero);
cadastros.add(c);
```

Se quiser limitar a quantidade de cadastros, basta verificar quantos cadastros existem, antes de adicionar:

```
if (cadastros.size() < MAX) {
    // pode adicionar
}
```

Aliás, `size()` também pode ser usado para saber quantos cadastros já foram feitos, eliminando a necessidade de ter um contador.

Já para percorrer os cadastros (nos métodos `listar()` e `buscar()`), basta usar um `for`:

```
for (Cadastro c: cadastros) {
    // usar c.getNome() e c.getNumero() conforme necessário
}
```